# Interpretation of first circa 70 000 blocks

Tags: money-supply

I've sampled a significant number of the first circa 70 000 blocks to conclude that they all serve only to create Bitcoins (50 at a time).  I will accept that my question does not have a factual answer and may therefore be closed on account of the speculation required to answer.  Nevertheless, the question is: is the 'money creation' of the first 70k transactions why some say that the creator of the system may be in possession of a third of the bitcoins ever created?

Comment: I notice another user has asked which block 'spends' the first coins.  The answer reveals that block 170 does so.  The conclusion of my own question is thus inaccurate to some extent, but perhaps a large number of coins were still created early in the process and may still be in possession of a few?

Comment: "some say" [WP:WEASEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Avoid_weasel_words#Unsupported_attributions) - Consider editing your post to make it answerable.

Comment: I apologize to the community for a poorly worded question and accept the closure reasons.  I did find a useful paper (http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/584.pdf) that concludes many BTCs have been hoarded.  This goes some way towards answering my question.  I've decided not to reword or re-open.